# Is any possibility to allow jsoncpp to parse non-valid JSON with property names without quotes?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

We have a huge JSON file editable by hands.
We want to allow non-valid JSON (e.g. {name: "value"}) as valid input for [Json::Reader::parse](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_reader.html#f1da6c976ad1e96c742804c3853eef94) method.

Comment: You could "pre-parse" it yourself before passing it to jsoncpp or you could fix the source JSON itself. If you're already editing it by hand, write it by hand properly

Comment: That's an issue. Too much quotes (two keystrokes) when editing JSON.